# Python: Finding out if certain words in a list are actual English words or close to English words

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I am working on a problem where I get a lot of words with their frequency of occurrence listed. Here is a sample of what I get:

```
drqsQAzaQ:1
OnKxnXecCINJ:1
QoGzQpg:1
cordially:1
Sponsorship:1
zQnpzQou:1
Thriving:1
febrero:1
rzaye:1
VseKEX:1
contributed:1
SNfXQoWV:1
hRwzmPR:1
Happening:1
TzJYAMWAQUIJTkWYBX:1
DYeUIqf:1
formats:1
eiizh:1
wIThY:1
infonewsletter:8
BusinessManager:10
MailScanner:12
```

As you can see, words like 'cordially' are actual English words, while words like 'infonewsletter' are not actual English words by themselves, but we can see that they are actually in English and mean something. However, words like 'OnKxnXecCINJ' do not mean anything (actually they are words from another charset, but I am ignoring them in my exercise and sticking to English) - I can discard them as junk

What would be the best method in Python to detect and eliminate such junk words from a given dictionary such as the one above?

I tried examining each word using nltk.corpus.word.words(), but it is killing my performance as my data set is very huge. Moreover, I am not certain whether this will give me a True for words like 'infonewsletter'

Please help.

Thanks,
Mahesh.

Comment: Post your code so we can help you very well.

Answer (score 5):

If the words are from *completely* different script within *Unicode* like `CJK` characters or Greek, Cyrillic, Thai, you could use `unicodedata.category` to see if they're letters to begin with (category starts with `L`):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category('a')
'Ll'
>>> unicodedata.category('E')
'Lu'
>>> unicodedata.category('中')
'Lo'
>>> [unicodedata.category(i).startswith('L') for i in 'aE中,']
[True, True, True, False]
```

Then you can use the `unicodedata.name` to see that they're Latin letters:

```
>>> 'LATIN' in unicodedata.name('a')
True
>>> 'LATIN' in unicodedata.false('中')
False
```

Presumably it is not an English-language word if it has non-Latin letters in it.

---

Otherwise, you could use a letter bigram/trigram classifier to find out if there is a high probability these are English words. For example `OnKxnXecCINJ` contains `Kxn` which is a trigram that neither very probably exist in any single English language word, nor any concatenation of 2 words.

You can build one yourself from the corpus by splitting words into character trigrams, or you can use any of the existing libraries like [`langdetect`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect) or [`langid`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langid) or so.

Also, see that the corpus is a `set` for fast `in` operations; only after the algorithm tells that there is a high probability it is in English, and the word fails to be found in the `set`, consider that it is alike to `infonewsletter` - a concatenation of several words; split it recursively into smaller chunks and see that each part thereof is found in the corpus.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I am trying out this approach. However, I have a question. I have a word 'vdgutumvjaxbpz'. I know this is junk. I wrote some code to get all grams of this word, 4-gram and higher. This was the result:

['vdgu', 'dgut', 'gutu', 'utum', 'tumv', 'umvj', 'mvja', 'vjax', 'jaxb', 'axbp', 'xbpz', 'vdgut', 'dgutu', 'gutum', 'utumv', 'tumvj', 'umvja', 'mvjax', 'vjaxb', 'jaxbp', 'axbpz', 'vdgutu', 'dgutum', 'gutumv', 'utumvj', 'tumvja', 'umvjax', 'mvjaxb', 'vjaxbp', 'jaxbpz', 'vdgutum', 'dgutumv', 'gutumvj', 'utumvja', 'tumvjax', 'umvjaxb', 'mvjaxbp', 'vjaxbpz', 'vdgutumv', 'dgutumvj', 'gutumvja', 'utumvjax', 'tumvjaxb', 'umvjaxbp', 'mvjaxbpz', 'vdgutumvj', 'dgutumvja', 'gutumvjax', 'utumvjaxb', 'tumvjaxbp', 'umvjaxbpz', 'vdgutumvja', 'dgutumvjax', 'gutumvjaxb', 'utumvjaxbp', 'tumvjaxbpz', 'vdgutumvjax', 'dgutumvjaxb', 'gutumvjaxbp', 'utumvjaxbpz', 'vdgutumvjaxb', 'dgutumvjaxbp', 'gutumvjaxbpz', 'vdgutumvjaxbp', 'dgutumvjaxbpz', 'vdgutumvjaxbpz']

Now, I compared each gram result with nltk.corpus.words.words() and found the intersection of the 2 sets.

```
vocab = nltk.corpus.words.words()
vocab = set(w.lower().strip() for w in vocab)

def GetGramsInVocab(listOfGrams, vocab):
    text_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in listOfGrams if w.isalpha())
    common = text_vocab & vocab
    return list(common)
```

However, the intersection contains 'utum', whereas I expected it to be NULL.

Also,

```
print("utum" in vocab)
```

returned true.

This does not make sense to me. I peeked into the vocabulary and found 'utum' in a few words like autumnian and metascutum

However, 'utum' is not a word by itself and I expected nltk to return false. Is there a more accurate corpus I can check against that would do whole word comparisons?

Also, I did a simple set operations test:

```
set1 = {"cutums" "acutum"}
print("utum" in set1)
```

This returned False as expected.

I guess I am confused as to why the code says 'utum' is present in the nltk words corpus.

Thanks,
Mahesh.